# In Vue.js app; how to add 'active' class to button in v-for loop

Tags: vue.js

In my Vue app: I'm using v-for to render product divs, each of which with a pair of buttons, 'new' and 'used', and I want to add 'active' class when a button is clicked. Problem is that I'm adding 'active' class to either all 'new' buttons or all 'used' buttons; pretty sure there's a Vue way to do this, other than getting the index of the clicked button and setting class to corresponding el. What am I missing?

markup:

```
<div id="app">
    <div class="products">

        <div class="product" v-for="product in products" :key="product.productID">
            <div class="product-image">
                <img :src=product.imgDef :alt="product.name" v-bind:title="product.name" />
            </div>
            <div class="product-summary">
                <p>{{ product.name }}</p>
                <p>{{ product.info }}</p>
                <ul>
                    <li v-for="detail in product.details">{{ detail }}</li>
                </ul>

                <div
                    class="conditions"
                    v-for="variant in product.variants"
                    v-bind:key="variant.variantID"
                    v-bind:style="variant.variantStyleObj"
                >
                    <!--
                        renders a 'new' button and a 'used' button in each div.product;
                        - clicking should add 'active' class only to clicked button
                    -->
                    <button
                        type="button"
                        v-on:click="updateProductImage(variant.variantImage, variant.variantID, product.productID, variant.condition)"
                        :class="[ 'condition', variant.condition, {active: conditionClass == variant.condition} ]"
                    >
                    {{ variant.condition }}
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div><!-- END .product-summary -->
        </div><!-- END .product -->
</div><!-- END #app -->
```

js:

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        products: [
            {
                productID: 1,
                name: "",
                info: "",
                imgDef: "../../images-dev/...jpg",
                details: [],
                inStock: false,
                variants: [
                    {
                        variantID: "123",
                        variantImage: "../../images-dev/1a.jpg",
                        condition: "new"
                    },
                    {
                        variantID: "321",
                        variantImage: "../../images-dev/1b.jpg",
                        condition: "used"
                    }
                ],
                inventory: 9
            },
        cart: 0,
        // conditionClass: ""
    },
    methods: {
        addToCart: function() {
            this.cart += 3;
        },
        updateProductImage: function(variantImage, variantKey, productKey, variantCondition) {
            this.products[productKey-1].imgDef = variantImage;
            this.conditionClass = variantCondition;
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: make a conditionClass for every variants and change that instead of the global conditionClass

Comment: Thanks @JulioGuerra. How would you solve this if you couldn't touch the data structure?

Comment: It's going to be possible to active multiple buttons at the same time ?

Comment: no, only one active button in the view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to change `products` array, you can, instead of using a single global `conditionClass`:

```js
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        // ...
        cart: 0,
        conditionClass: ""
    },
```

Make it into an object, in a way that it will work as a map that will have the `productID` as keys and the product's `conditionClass`.

[**Demo JSFiddle here**](https://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/beh4xs9g/).

Example:

```js
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        // ...
        cart: 0,
        conditionClass: {} // initialize as empty object
    },
```

Change the `:class` to access `conditionClass` via a key (stripped other parts for brevity):

From

```html
<button ... :class="[{active: conditionClass == variant.condition}]">
```

To:

```html
<button ... :class="[{active: conditionClass[product.productID] == variant.condition}]">
```

And, finally, set the key in the method:

```js
updateProductImage: function(variantImage, variantKey, productKey, variantCondition) {
  this.products[productKey - 1].imgDef = variantImage;
  // line below was: this.conditionClass = variantCondition;
  Vue.set(this.conditionClass, productKey, variantCondition);
}
```

Comment: Thank you @acdcjunior. I noticed in your Fiddle that your solution allows either 'new' or 'used' left active *per product*; though my intention was to have only a single active button in the view, your version is perhaps a useful feature. I'll have a go implementing your approach shortly, cheers.

Comment: Ah, if you want only one active for the whole app, use, instead, in the last line of that method: `Vue.set(this, 'conditionClass', {[productKey]: variantCondition});`

Comment: Thanks again @acdcjunior, for your solution and for leading me to read up on Vue.set